# What was the function of ring-shaped module in 22nd century Vulcan ships?

Tags: star-trek, tv, spaceship, star-trek-enterprise

All 22nd century Vulcan ships had a ring-shaped module. Not just starships, but small shuttle pods also had this module. As Vulcans do everything logically, there must be some purposes of those modules. A repeating structure in all ships can't be a coincidence.

Over half decade has passed since I last watched *Star Trek: Enterprise* TV Series. So, I'm unable to recall the functions if they were ever mentioned in the show. Do you've those things in mind? Other sources are warmly welcome.

[image: Vulcan Combat Cruiser]

[image: Vulcan Starship]

[image: Vulcan Starship at Warp]

Here's small Shuttle pod:

[image: Vulcan Shuttle Pod]

Comment: That ring is more obviously a drive than anything else I've seen that didn't spit fire out the back.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In an article for [Star Trek : The Magazine](http://fsd.trekships.org/art/timur.html) ("***Designing the Ti'Mur***"), Doug Drexler; Senior Production Artist for ST: Enterprise described the circular hoop feature as **[warp nacelles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Nacelle)**:

> '*Ah,*' I thought, as I mulled over the Vulcan ship design question for
>   Enterprise. '*This is the perfect place to fit the hoop ship.*' "*The
>   script stated that Trip would be ga-ga over this Surak-class starship.
>   After laying eyes on it, there was no question in my mind that he
>   [Matt Jeffries] went to bed that night puzzling out the exotic shape.*
>
> The other change involved eliminating any physical connection between
>   the main body of the ship and the hoop, so they are actually separate
>   elements. *"We liked the defiance of conventional structural
>   support,"* Drexler explains. *"It makes the Vulcans look like they
>   control powers beyond human ken. This was true of the original TV
>   Enterprise. **Those struts that support the nacelles defy what we
>   understand today.** It says that these people are masters of
>   technologies that we don't yet understand. It speaks volumes for the
>   technology at play."*
>    <sub><sup>- JULY 2002 ISSUE 39 STAR TREK: THE
>   MAGAZINE</sup></sub>

Rick Sternbach; Senior Production Illustrator for ST: Enterprise [described](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/TNG_studio_models) the circular hoop feature as an **annular warp ring**:

> Abandoning the preliminary design lines which echoed the design of the
>   long range shuttle, Sternbach arrived at a final version in September
>   1991 and his notes on the final design read, "Vulcan Ship V Variant of
>   Annular; No windows or other details; basic body shape." Later he
>   recalled, *"The commandeered Vulcan ships in "Unification" followed a
>   pretty familiar approvals flow of initial idea, producer changes, and
>   final concept to go to the model maker, in this case Greg Jein. Since
>   we hadn't seen much in the way of Vulcan ship technology, beyond the
>   motion picture shuttle, it was a bit daunting to home in on a true
>   Vulcan style, and I can't say I'm terribly happy with the final
>   result. Hindsight always invokes a desire for more design time, which
>   might have helped. **Perhaps different proportions on the annular warp
>   ring**, more curves, and more positive-negative surface detailing."*  <sub><sup>- Star Trek: The Magazine Volume 3, Issue 8, page 104</sup></sub>

---

Michael Okuda, Art Supervisor for ST: Enterprise has offered an [in-depth treknobabble explanation](http://web.archive.org/web/20120128043029/http://drexfiles.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/let-the-countdown-begin-2011-sotl-%E2%80%93-sneak-peek-02-mark-rademaker/) of how the rings create a warp field:

> One of the most radical experiments in early Earth starship design was
>   the Enterprise XCV.  Unlike the traditional nacelle-and-saucer
>   configuration, **the XCV uses an annular propulsion system, based on
>   Vulcan vehicle designs.**  This ship however, employed cyclotron
>   accelerators to create a high-energy proton flux.  **The protons circled
>   through the massive outer rings of verterium gallenide segments,
>   generating a symmetrical subspace field.  Each of the two coleopter
>   ring structures contained two counter-rotating cyclotrons.  The
>   cyclotrons in each ring operated slightly out of phase with each
>   other, generating the propulsive field imbalance that carried the ship
>   through subspace at warp speeds.**

Comment: Weird, 'annular warp ring' is like 'ATM machine'. Annular means ring-shaped.

Comment: @Keen -As in "*annular confinement beam*" (a beam that goes around the person)

Comment: @user1027 true. I'll try to see if we can fix it after I complete my CPR heart and lung recovery course and get caught up on all my DHS national defense paperwork.

Answer (score 24):

The rings are [warp nacelles](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/D%27Kyr_type#Technical_data).

Comment: Not everyone needs the whole phallic symbolism of Kirk's ship :-)

Comment: What's Warp Nacelles doing in Shuttle Pod??

Comment: @SachinShekhar most [starfleet shuttlecraft](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Shuttlecraft) had warp, though slower and shorter-range than their motherships

Comment: @Jeff, it could be argued that the Vulcan ships (particularly the lowest one, above) show even greater, er, symbolism.

Comment: If Starfleet nacelles are phallic, then the Vulcan nacelles would be their, er, counterpart?

Answer (score 6):

The Vulcan warp rings look similar to the proposed [Alcubierre drive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcubierre_drive), and may have been influenced by that concept.  It was first proposed in 1994, and Enterprise premiered in 2001.  Due to work by NASA's Dr. Harold "Sonny" White, a ring configuration came to be seen as more efficient than Alcubierre's original geometry; however, White's design ideas were not published until 2003 (White, H., “A Discussion on space-time metric engineering,” Gen. Rel. Grav. 35, 2025-2033) and did not become widely known until 2011 ([Warp Field Mechanics 101](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110015936.pdf)), so the timing seems a bit problematic.

http://www.regeeken.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/warpdrivediagramedited.jpg